# Main.java together with simple static double calculation

Tags: java, static, double

I'm working on a school assignment and I'm kinda confused right now. it would be awesome of somebody can point out the problem so I can learn from it. So here it is:

It's a simple calculation from miles to kilometers and vice verca. This is what I have:

```
public class Kilometer {

    static double mijlToKilometer(double mijl) {
        double kilometer = 1.609 * mijl;
        return kilometer;
    }

    static double kilometerToMijl(double kilometer) {
        double mijl = 0.622 * kilometer;
        return mijl;
    }
}
```

And this is the main:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("mijl?");
        double mijl = input.nextDouble();
        Kilometer eenBerekening = new Kilometer();
        eenBerekening.mijl = mijl;
        eenBerekening.mijlToKilometer();

        System.out.println("kilometer?");
        double kilometer = input.nextDouble();
        eenBerekening.kilometer = kilometer;
        eenBerekening.kilometerToMijl();
    }

}
```

I do have the "import java.util.Scanner;" line so it's not that. Netbeans is giving a problem at these lines:

```
    Kilometer eenBerekening = new Kilometer();
    eenBerekening.mijl = mijl;
    eenBerekening.mijlToKilometer();
```

Help anyone? Thx in advance!!

**UPDATE**
So this is what I have right now and it's working. Thx for all the help!!!

Kilometer.java

```
public class Kilometer {

    static double mijlToKilometer(double mijl) {
        double kilometer = 1.609 * mijl;
        System.out.println(kilometer);
        return kilometer;
    }

    static double kilometerToMijl(double kilometer) {
        double mijl = 0.622 * kilometer;
        System.out.println(mijl);
        return mijl;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("mijl?");
        double mijl = input.nextDouble();
        Kilometer.mijlToKilometer(mijl);

        System.out.println("kilometer?");
        double kilometer = input.nextDouble();
        Kilometer.kilometerToMijl(kilometer); 
    }

}
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Cannot find symbol. That's what it says

Comment: I don't see mijl anywhere in you KIlometer class.

Comment: I'm sry if I wasnt specific enough. I did make a screenshot and uploaded it. Here's the link: http://i39.tinypic.com/v2uts3.jpg

Comment: @Andrew Ng, Please paste the error message into your question, and tell us to which lines in your code the line numbers in the error message correspond.

Answer (score 2):

You class `Kilometer` doesn't have a field called `mijl`, that's why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a `mijl` attribute on your `Kilometer` class. And as pointed out by others your `Kilometer` methods are static. Just call it from the class, you do not need an instance:

```
Kilometer.mijlToKilometer(mijl);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    Kilometer eenBerekening = new Kilometer();
>    eenBerekening.mijl = mijl;
> ```

You're creating an instance of class `Kilometer` and assigning to a property that is not defined in that class.

> ```
>    eenBerekening.kilometerToMijl();
> ```

Here you're calling a `static` method on an instance and failing to pass in the required parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("mijl?");
        double mijl = input.nextDouble();
        Kilometer eenBerekening = new Kilometer();

        Kilometer.mijlToKilometer(mijl); //calling static class and passing parameter to function

        System.out.println("kilometer?");
        double kilometer = input.nextDouble();

        Kilometer.kilometerToMijl(kilometer); // same as before but other function
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the keyword `static` for your method declaration when you are in fact calling them using an instance.

Also, you trying to set

```
eenBerekening.mijl = mijl;
```

while you have no class parameter `mijl` in your class. Just call your method with

```
eenBerekening.mijlToKilometer(mijl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have static methods. These methods are at Class-Level not at instance-level, so you have to call:

```
Kilometer.mijlToKilometer()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared these methods static, you don't need an instance of Kilometer to use them, you can just do:

```
Kilometer.mijlToKilometer(12.02)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The methods are `static`, so you don't need to `new`.
2. There's no `mijl` field of the `Kilometer` class, public or otherwise.
3. The `static` methods on `Kilometer` expect a parameter, but your code does not pass one.

So:

```
double mijl = input.nextDouble();
double kilometer = Kilometer.mijlToKilometer(mijl);
```